# Does Linux Kernel Object file(. ko) has structure?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, reverse-engineering, kernel-module

I have a linux kernel module and it has tampering resist mechanism.

When insmod the module check module's integrity in its init function.

To test this mechanism, I changed kernel module's binary a little bit.

For specify this job. Changed contents was 2 byte of certain offset of module file. (00 02 -> 02 00 in hex representation)

I insmod the tampered module then, I got killed message and occured kernel oops.

dmesg says unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffc900209aa7d1.
 for addition it last process of call trace was find_symbol_in_section+0x39/0xda.

I guess that  module's address or something value related to insmod process has changed and causes kernel oops.

So I think it would be helpful that let me know information about kernel object file structure.

Comment: You can take your favorite search engine and ask it to find you a reference. SO is not for external resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [man page for init_module(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/init_module) Linux kernel modules use the ELF file format. You can use a utility like [objdump(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) or [readelf(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf) to get read information from it.